# Update of the weight of a configured product (in Woocommerce) with transfer of the variables via (Admin)Ajax for the shopping cart

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

Update of the weight of a configured product with transfer of the variables via (Admin)Ajax for the shopping cart ...
The problem is that the weight has to be calculated via jQuery first, then sent via AJAX so that the total weight in the shopping cart is updated. I have tried and asked a lot, nobody has a solution, that the passing to the PHP variable in question somehow doesn't work or I didn't succeed (I'm not so firm in PHP), maybe there is not much missing, here is my last code:

in funktions.php:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/weight_hardox.js', array('jquery') );

// in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),'gewt' => 0, 'gewt_ges' => 0, ) );
// Same handler function...
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action() {
    global $wpdb;
    $gewicht = floatval( $_POST['gewicht'] );
    $gesamtgewicht = floatval( $_POST['gesamtgewicht'] );
        echo 'gewicht:' . $gewicht;
         echo '<small>Gewicht update: ' . $gewicht.'+'. $gesamtgewicht. ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit') . '</small>';
    wp_die();
}
```

the weight_hardox.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    var myurl = document.URL;  //console.log('myurl '+myurl );
                    var gew_h=0;
                    var vGwges=0;
                    var sum=0;
                    var gewt1=0;
                    var gewt=0;
                    var gew_hs=0;
if ( (myurl.indexOf("warenkorb") != -1) || (myurl.indexOf("kasse") != -1) || (myurl.indexOf("hardox-500-zuschnitt") != -1) ) {

            //.single-product calc weight
            //if (myurl.indexOf("hardox-500-zuschnitt") != -1) {
            jQuery(document).on('change', '.single-product .summary .cart input', function() {
                        var vmats=parseFloat(jQuery( '.uni-module-radio input:checked+.uni-cpo-radio-option-label .uni-cpo-option-label__text' ).text());   console.log('ok fs ' + vmats);
                        var vLgs=parseFloat(jQuery( '#uni_cpo_laenge2-field' ).val());   //console.log('ok fs ' + vLgs);
                        var vBts=parseFloat(jQuery( '#uni_cpo_breite_hardox_rq2-field' ).val());   //console.log('ok fs ' + vBts);
                        var vSts=parseFloat(jQuery( '#uni_cpo_stckzahl-field' ).val());   //console.log('ok fs ' + vSts);
                        gewt = parseFloat(vmats*vLgs*vBts*vSts*0.000008);   //
                        gewt = parseFloat((gewt).toFixed(3));   console.log('gew_hs ' + gewt);
                        var vGws = jQuery( '#gewb' ).text();
                            vGws = jQuery( '#gewb' ).text(gewt); 
                                window.setTimeout(function(){  
                                    vGws = jQuery( '#gewb' ).text(); console.log('vGws>ingle ' + vGws); 
                                },990);
                        var data = {
                            'action': 'my_action',
                            'gewicht' : ajax_object.gewt,
                            'gesamtgewicht' : ajax_object.gewt_ges
                            //'whatever': ajax_object.we_value      //We pass php values differently!
                        };
                        // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
                        /**/ jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
                            response+=gewt;
                        console.log('Got this from the server: weight: '  +gewt +'/ update total weight: ' + gewt_ges +' / response: ' +response);
                        $( ".total-weight").after('<tr id="gew_z"></tr>');
                        $( "#gew_z" ).html('<th>Gewicht-HardoxV1</th><td><span class="kg">'+ gewt+'kg</span></td>');
                        $( ".total-weight td").text(gewt_ges + " kg"); 
                            //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);

                        });
            });



        /* var jqxhr = $.post('https://arthouse39.de/wdl/wp-content/themes/childtheme_z/test.php',{gew_hs: gew_hs}, function() {
            //alert( "success" );
            })
         .done(function( data ) {
            console.log( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        //$( "#gew_z" ).html('<span class="Sendungsdaten_txt">Sendungsdaten:</span>'+ data ).show(399).delay( 3700 ).fadeOut( 700 );
            })  
                                   return false; 
                e.preventDefault();*/ 

    //} 

                window.setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery(".cart_item" ).each( function( index, element ){
                var array = ( jQuery( this ).html() ); //console.log('array ' + array);
                        if ( (array.indexOf("Hardox-500") != -1) || (array.indexOf("Hardox") != -1) ) {
                        var vmat=jQuery(this).find( '.variation-Materialstrkemm > p' ).text();   //console.log('ok f ' + vmat);
                        var vLg=jQuery(this).find( '.variation-Lngemm > p' ).text();   //console.log('ok f ' + vLg);
                        var vBt=jQuery(this).find( '.variation-Breitemm > p' ).text();   //console.log('ok f ' + vBt);
                        var vSt=jQuery(this).find( '.variation-Stck > p' ).text();   //console.log('ok f ' + vSt);
                            gew_h = vmat*vLg*vBt*vSt*0.000008;   //console.log('gew_h ' + gew_h);
                            gew_h = parseFloat((gew_h).toFixed(2));
                            var vGw=jQuery(this).find( '.variation-Gewichtkg > p, #uni_cpo_gew_h5-field, #gewb' ).text();   //console.log('ok fgew ' + vGw);
                            vGW = jQuery(this).find( '.variation-Gewichtkg > p, #gewb' ).text(gew_h); 
                        }
                    });
                },700);

//gesamtgewicht berechnen - total weight (all products):
                window.setTimeout(function(){

                gewt1=parseFloat(jQuery(".total-weight td").html()); //         
                console.log('gewt 1: '+gewt1);

                        var myArray=0;

                            /* jQuery(".gewl" ).each( function( index, element ){
                              myArray =jQuery(this).find( '#gewb' ).text().replace(",", "."); */  
        jQuery("#gewb" ).each( function( index, element ){  
                            myArray =jQuery(this).text().replace(",", ".");
                            myarray=parseFloat(myArray);console.log('myArray ' +myArray);
                                       //gewt = gewt*1 + myArray*1;
                                       gewt+= myArray*1;
                                gewt_ges=gewt1+gewt;
                                gewt_ges=parseFloat((gewt_ges).toFixed(2));                                 
                                gewt=parseFloat((gewt).toFixed(2));   //
                                console.log('gewt wh...= ' + gewt);                         
        }); 
                        /* var data = {
                            'action': 'my_ajax_request',
                            'post_type': 'POST',
                            'name': 'My First AJAX Request'
                          };

                          jQuery.post("", data, function(response) {

                          }, 'json'); */
                        var data = {
                            'action': 'my_action',
                            'gewicht' : ajax_object.gewt,
                            'gesamtgewicht' : ajax_object.gewt_ges
                            //'whatever': ajax_object.we_value      //We pass php values differently!
                        };
                        // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
                        /**/ jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
                            response+=gewt;
                        console.log('Got this from the server: weight: '  +gewt +'/ update total weight: ' + gewt_ges +' / response: ' +response);
                        $( ".total-weight").after('<tr id="gew_z"></tr>');
                        $( "#gew_z" ).html('<th>Gewicht-HardoxV1</th><td><span class="kg">'+ gewt+'kg</span></td>');
                        $( ".total-weight td").text(gewt_ges + " kg"); 
                            //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);

                        });



                    /* var jqxhr = $.post('https://arthouse39.de/wdl/wp-content/themes/childtheme_z/test.php',{gew_hs: gewt},
                    //var jqxhr = $.post('https://arthouse39.de/wdl/wp-content/themes/childtheme_z/functions.php',{gew_hs: gewt},                   
                    function() { //alert( "success" );//alert( gew_h );
                            } )
                        .done(function( data ) {console.log( "Data Loaded: " + data );
                        $( "#gew_z" ).html('<span class="Sendungsdaten_txt">Gesamtgewicht incl. Hardox.: </span>'+ data + ' kg').show(399).delay( 3700 );
                        //$('.total-weight').html('<th>Gewicht</th><td data-title="Total Weight"><span class="kg">'+ data+'kg</span></td>');
                        }); */

                    //
                    },1390);
                    }
            } );
```

example from cart width the configured product (https://arthouse39.de/wdl/produkt/hardox-500-zuschnitt-generator-r-q-1/) in the console:

"... 
Got this from the server: weight: 177.41/ update total weight: 179.01 / response: gewicht:0Gewicht update: 0+0 kg177.41"

How do I get the value into the total weight so that the right shipping method can be chosen? (The transfer into the total-weight already works ... -but apparently only as a display?

Would be great if someone can help, if it costs something, please make an offer, thank you very much!

Comment: Update in js: jQuery('.woocommerce-tabs.wc-tabs-wrapper #tab-additional_information .woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value').text(response);

Comment: this updates / display the weight in single produkt tabs

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, sorry for my late answer, I thought I was notified, just saw it a moment ago. The products are configured using a plugin and an additional jQuery function in the weight_hardox.js calculates the weight.
As far as I have read, Ajax is required to pass a value/variable to the server to be able to use this value in PHP.
The functions to update the weight in the shopping cart are in the functions.php, but they do not work yet

Comment: the plugin for configurtion: Product Options and Price Calculation Formulas for WooCommerce – Uni CPO